# Connect to an UPnP Server as guest

Tags: network, file-transfer, file-sharing

I can connect to my UPnP file server (the server is my ASUS router actually) via **Connect to Server (⌘+K)** diagram in Finder (By the way this server don't show up in Network folder). I don't have write access on this server for huge files. I used to have write access for any size of files when it was connected as *Guest*.

Now I'm trying to connect to server as a Guest by disconnecting or ejecting the server and reconnecting using Connect to Server but it doesn't show me anything and just connect to server as my Mac user name.

Here is Finder connected to server as my Mac user name:

[image]

Here is c*onnect to server* diagram:

[image]

Here is the error I'm getting when I try to write big file in server:

I'm getting this error only on big file size. Small files copying fine. This file for example was more than `8GB`.

[image]

**How can I connect to this server as Guest?** I know if I connect as a guest again, it will solve my problem because it used to have no problem before.

**Environment Info:**

---

- OSX: 10.7 (Lion)
- Router: ASUS (RT-N56U)
- Mac: MacBook Air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an entry for the server in Keychain Access? If so, try deleting it. That could prevent you from automatically logging in as your user name.

Comment: Brilliant answer!